# Dependency issue installing DevStack

Tags: openstack, devstack

I am trying to install Openstack using DevStack. After correctly creating the user `stack` and running `./stack.sh`, the script starts to install the required dependencies until it hits `Obtaining file:///opt/stack/cinder`. Then I obtain the following errors:

`Exception:
ContextualVersionConflict: (grpcio 1.21.1 (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('grpcio<1.16.0,>=1.0.0'), set(['tooz']))`

I understand that there is a conflict in **grpcio**, but I don't know how to solve it. I already unsuccessfully tried to install a specific version between 1.0.0 and 1.16.0.

The Devstack version I am using is the latest from the git master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved the problem myself.

I had the **tooz** package installed with version 1.62 which was causing the issue.

After removing that package the installation completed.